# Checking for more than one condition in validation

Tags: java

Here is the full abstract class that is implemented. I wanted to know if there was a way I could return two exceptions if attack and the level of a warrior were 0. I want to display two messages when that is the case, but if I only test for each of them individually I cannot seem to throw the second message in the exception. For example if I test for attack <= 0 then it should tell me "attack cant be zero", but if attack <= 0 and defense <=0 it should tell me "attack cant be zero. defense cant be zero" I want to do that without having an if condition for every single possibility as it can get messy when more possibilities are added.

```
public abstract class Warrior {

public int level;
public int attack;
public int defense;

public abstract int getLevel();

public abstract int getAttack();

public abstract int getDefense();

public static abstract class Builder {

    public Warrior warrior;

    public Builder attack(int attack) {
        return this;
    }

    public Builder defense(int defense) {
        return this;
    }

    public Warrior build() {
        return warrior;
    }

    public void validate(Warrior W) {

        if (W.level <= 0 && W.attack > 0 && W.defense > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (W.defense <= 0 && W.attack > 0 && W.level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Defense must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (W.attack <= 0 && W.defense > 0 && W.level > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Attack must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (W.attack <= 0 && W.level <= 0 && W.defense > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. Attack must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (W.level <= 0 && W.defense <= 0 && W.attack > 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Level must be greater than 0. Defense must be greater than 0. ");

        } else if (W.level <= 0 && W.defense <= 0 && W.attack <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Level must be greater than 0. Attack must be greater than 0. Defense must be greater than 0. ");
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you should be handling this by throwing exceptions? Exceptions are for exceptional behavior, not for controlling flow of a program.

Comment: I have to use throw exceptions based on the way the tests were given to me. Hence the use of this long if else.

Comment: I am looking for a way to not have to throw an exception to every single combination that can be invalid. Since the messages are the same I want to be able to throw the two messages at the same time instead of creating a new string with the combined messages.

Comment: You should check the conditions in the order you want them to be shown. Only the first one detected will be thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check each condition on its own and append the desired sub message to a result message and throw an exception if the message has a length > 0. Something like:

```
public void validate(Warrior W) {
    String message = "";
    if (W.level <= 0) {
        message += "Level must be greater than 0. ";
    }
    if (W.defense <= 0) {
        message += "Defense must be greater than 0. ";
    }
    if (W.attack <= 0) {
         message += "Attack must be greater than 0. ";
    }
    if (!message.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(message);
    } 
    else {                   
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem and it looks much cleaner than the method I provided.

Comment: @ShreyanshVyas You are welcome. Glad if I could help.